# String literals turning into nullchars on passing to a function

Tags: c, string, operating-system, literals, bare-metal

I am in the process of making a simple kernel, and I have run into an issue with passing a string literal to a function as a `char*`.

Printing any char from the string that is passed into the function results in a nullchar, I tested this my printing the first char + 48, which printed a 0. I am not sure weather this may be due to the command i am using to compile, I am compiling with the following GCC flags `-fno-stack-protector -mgeneral-regs-only -mno-red-zone -ffreestanding -fno-pie -m32 -nostdinc -nostdlib`

I have checked that the string literal is in the assembly by compiling to assembly.

Main file:

```c
#include "../drivers/ports.h"
#include "../drivers/screen.h"

void main()
{
    clear_screen();

    kprint_at("hhgfhehthdtydhgf", 1, 6);
    /*
    kprint_at("This text spans multiple lines", 75, 10);
    kprint_at("There is a line\nbreak", 0, 20);
    kprint("There is a line\nbreak");
    kprint_at("What happens when we run out of space?", 45, 24);
    */
}
```

in the screen.c file

```c
void kprint_at(char *message, int col, int row)
{
    print_char(message[0] + 48, col, row, WHITE_ON_BLACK); // prints a 0 to the screen, ascii 48

    int offset;
    if (col >= 0 && row >= 0)
    {
        offset = get_offset(col, row);
    }
    else
    {
        offset = get_cursor_offset();
        row = get_offset_row(offset);
        col = get_offset_col(offset);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (message[i] != 0)
    {
        offset = print_char(message[i++], col, row, WHITE_ON_BLACK);
        row = get_offset_row(offset);
        col = get_offset_col(offset);
    }
}
```

I have verified the correct operation of all the functions called from the `kprint_at` function.

Comment: Just to make sure: `screen.h` has a function prototype of `kprint_at`, right?

Comment: OK, a standard question. Do you have some custom startup code? This won't link the standard runtime library and therefore won't initialize your .bss and .data sections (and won't do some other essential thing too).

Comment: Yeah, i have a bootloader, and screen.h does have the function prototype, since I am able to call it and check that they are nullchars. Here is the source code if you want to have a look at the bootloader https://github.com/finlaymorrison/os

Comment: how do you check it

Comment: Why are you adding `48` to your `message[0]`? This will result in `'h'+48`

Comment: it prints out the ascii value of '0', hence the value of `message[0]` is a nullchar. This is the issue I am happening

Comment: If this is the only evidence, then it is not very convincing. Anyway, looks like your startup code in kernel/entry.asm is only calling `main` without doing anything else

Comment: In your startup code you just call `main` it is far not enough.